# pip subprocess to install build dependencies

Tags: python

I can't install Python libraries on Termux :

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

```
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for maturin      Failed to build maturin

  ERROR: Could not build wheels for maturin, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

```
                                            × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.                        │ exit code: 1
```

╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

~[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dnPV.jpg) $